# Does deleting the copy constructor also deletes default copy/move operators?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy

I have a class that I do not intend to copy/move around and want to make sure I don't accidentally do that.

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo(const Foo&) = delete;

  // Are these 3 needed?
  Foo(Foo&) = delete;
  Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;
  Foo& operator=(Foo&&) = delete;
}
```

Is there any purpose of also deleting the move constructor and/or the move/copy assignment operators, or does deleting the copy constructor automatically tells the compiler to not generate them?

Comment: "or does deleting the copy constructor automatically tells the compiler to not generate them?" Why don't you just try?

Comment: @Jodocus, because there is always more than trial and error. Theory answers the most important question in engineering: **Why!?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Deleted_implicitly-declared_default_constructor) [on](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Deleted_implicitly-declared_copy_constructor) [when](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment#Deleted_implicitly-declared_move_assignment_operator) [such](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Deleted_implicitly-declared_copy_assignment_operator) functions are implicitly deleted and when not. So the short answer to your question without repeating what is written in the documentary:

> Is there any purpose of also deleting the move constructor and/or the move/copy assignment operators [...]?

Yes, there certainly is. Even if it is just emphasizing more strongly in a redundant way that a particular operation is not permitted, so it may make the interface of your code more expressive.